# Possible to add a new font to Google font?

Tags: google, fonts

The question seems weird but would it be possible to add a new font to Google Font? I have a website that easily uses google font but adding a new one is a pain.

Answer (score 4):

You can read through the process of submitting a new font in the [Google Fonts Guide](https://googlefonts.github.io/gf-guide/).

> This guide aims to help people navigate the **requirements and
> recommendations for contributing to Google Fonts**. The contents covered
> here range from general knowledge to contextualize the what and why of
> some of the requirements as well as the specifics regarding technical
> aspects with some suggestions on how to comply with them. It covers
> different levels of information for both newcomers and more
> experienced contributors.

Comment: thanks for this documentation Pete!

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, it is not possible for you to add a new font to Google Fonts because Google Fonts is a curated library of fonts, and only fonts that meet Google's specific criteria are added to the library. But I am not sure, maybe it's possible. I didn't try this in recent times.

If I find something important related to this, I will definitely share it with you.

Thanks